# How to distributed order between all participants?

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, rabbitmq, message-queue, distributed-system

There is system that has three business participants:

1. performers
2. customers (mobile device, web interface)
3. orders

When customer creates an order it should be distributed between all exists performers and then system have to decide which performer will get order. At the same some others can not get this order too if one has accepted.

Which architecture approach and tools, protocols to use?

Is it right statement that if I have distributed business model it means I have to use distributed systems like Rabbit, Kafka?

I know this question is so widely, but anyway I will be glad to get any suggestions and recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, two types of messaging model are distinguished - [*point-to-point model*](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/PointToPointChannel.html) (queue semantic) and [*publisher-subscriber model*](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/PublishSubscribeChannel.html) (topic semantic). From your question it seems that you need to implement point-to-point model. So, basically, some `customer` service will publish `order` to the queue and single `performer` will receive and process it. This way dispatching `orders` between `performers` is handled automatically by messaging system.

Regarding concrete messaging system - you can use either Kafka or RabbitMQ, or any other messaging broker, since most of them supports point-to-point nowadays.

For example, [with Kafka you can achieve point-to-point](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/CompetingConsumers.html) by having `orders` Kafka-topic, and putting all `performers` in single consumer group. This way when `order` comes, it will be load-balanced by Kafka among `performers` in the same consumer group, so only one `performer` will receive and process it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at [Cadence Workflow](https://cadenceworkflow.io/). Its programming model greatly simplifies implementation of such service orchestration use cases.

Messaging systems are not a good fit for service orchestration that goes beyond simple streaming or notification scenarios.